# Choose between Mac OSX and Windows 10 at startup

Tags: macos, mac, windows-10, multi-boot, boot-camp

I have a MAC where I have installed OSX 10.10  and Windows 10 using bootcamp.

When I'm on one of systems , I can restart to other and vice versa.

I want to know if is there any utility or configuration  that make possible on computer startup , to choose on which system I want to boot ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Built into MAC OS, there are currently no ways to always have a boot menu show at startup, at least as far as I know. There are 2 ways to accomplish what you want:

1. At startup, you can hold the Alt/Option key which will load the boot-manager and allow you to choose whichever partition you would like.
2. You can install a 3rd party boot-manager that will automatically load and prompt with each startup. One of the most notable boot managers is [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

I have used rEFInd before, and it works as intended - However, if you wish to remove this, it can be quite the task, so keep that in mind.

If you don't mind having to physically press and hold the Alt/Option key at startup, you may want to start with that option.